# Is it possible to set a primary foreign key through a navigation property from another table?

Tags: breeze

I have a table, TaxReturn, which has a Primary Foreign key of ProcessID, that is mapped to the Process tables Primary key of ProcessID. I need to set the ProcessID of TaxReturn to the ProcessID of the Process table. How can I do this with Breeze so I am not saving twice and making two round trips to the database?

Answer (score 0):

May I rephrase?

- You have two tables, `Process` and `TaxReturn`
- `Process` has a 1..(0,1) association with `TaxReturn`
- `ProcessID` is the PK of `Process`
- `ProcessID` is the PK of `TaxReturn` and is also the FK to the parent `Process`

Thus a `Process` can have zero or one `TaxReturn`s.

If you create and save a`Process` and `TaxReturn` at the same time (assuming the camelCase `NamingConvention`):

```
var process = manager.createEntity('Process');
var taxReturn = manager.createEntity('TaxReturn', {ProcessID: process.processID});
// ... fill them in
return manager.saveChanges(); // Breeze saves them together in a single transaction.
```

If you add a `TaxReturn` to an existing `Process`:

```
var taxReturn = manager.createEntity('TaxReturn', {ProcessID: existingProcess.processID});
// ... fill them in
return manager.saveChanges(); // saves the new TaxReturn.
```